# config dict construction pattern, using a helper class?

Tags: python, class, dictionary

Someone suggested to me that as a convention, one could support construction of a config `dict` in Python with the help of an "options" class, like so:

```
...
config = {Options.A: 10, Options.B: 20} # produces config = {"A": 10, "B": 20}
result = myObj.someMethod(value, config)
...
```

The idea here I believe is to provide a menu of options for a client user to pick from, instead of relying on the user to construct the config `dict` from scratch - I guess one benefit would be elimination of config field typos, and perhaps it could help with forward compatibility.

The only way I can think of to support this is to implement an `Options` class that would look something like this:

```
class Options:
    A = "A"
    B = "B"
```

However, this feels bad in many ways. It's brittle because if the user code clobbers any of the Options class fields (e.g. `Options.A="garbage"`) then it's broken. And anyway, implementing those fields like `A = "A"` just feels plain silly. Besides, if we're implementing an Options class shouldn't we should just be using Options objects directly instead of using the Options class to produce a `dict`?

So, is there a more elegant and effective way to implement the desired `config = {Options.A: 10, Options.B: 20}` pattern, or something similar? Is this pattern familiar at all?

**EDIT:** in case this wasn't clear, the config dict need only contain a small subset of the available options.

Comment: Did this someone happen to elaborate a bit more than this? As it stands - I can't see what their intention was or how this could be of any benefit...

Comment: From everyone's responses, I gather the pattern itself is not common let alone useful, so a discussion on how to implement it is probably not very useful either - but thanks everyone for helping me confirm that this really isn't something worth trying to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand the intended purpose nor expected benefice ... but if you're looking for an helper to construct and validate your dictionary, something like that might be a good starting point:

```
def config(**kwargs):
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        if key not in AllowedKeys:
            raise KeyError("{} is not allowed in config".format(key))

        if not value_is_correct_for_key(key, value):
            raise ValueError("{} is not allowed for {} in config".format(value, key))

        # ... more tests here depending on your use case

    # Everything is OK,  just return the dictionary
    return kwargs



# Usage:
print(config(A="1", B="2"))
```

Comment: Slight nitpicks: it's a bit odd seeing `not key in AllowedKeys` - while valid, it's commonly written as `key not in AllowedKeys`. As for the `raise` it wouldn't hurt to include the key/value that's caused it for informational purposes

Comment: @JonClements The `not key in` was a typo -- fixed now. As for the rest, I agree, but this code was mostly intended to be a starting point. Anyway, I add some context info while raising the exceptions. I hope I don't introduced other typos by doing so ;)

Comment: I like this idea, and decided to implement this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand the purpose of this construct. If you wish to ensure that the user only uses valid keys for the config `dict`, I would protect the attributes with the `property` decorator (see http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property):

```
class Options:
    def __init__(self):
        self._A = 'A'
        self._B = 'B'
        # etc.

    @property
    def A(self):
        return self._A

    @property
    def B(self):
        return self._B

    # etc.
```

Not that completely prevents the user to mess up your class, but at least it's less easy to do so.